# Want all diagonals in a mxn matrix in JAVA

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

my matrix is

```
0  1  2  3  4  
5  6  7  8  9  
10 11 12 12 14  
15 16 17 18 19
```

I want to print

```
4  
3 9  
2 8 14  
1 7 12 19  
0 6 12 18  
5 11 17  
10 16  
15
```

Thanks in advance. this code is checking for the other diagonals

current code is:

```
int rows = 5;
        int cols = 8;
        int maxSum = rows + cols - 2;

        for (int sum = 0; sum <= maxSum; sum++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    if (i + j - sum == 0) {
                       // work is done here

                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

I have tried alot but the other diagonals are not getting checked.

Comment: i am getting all the other diagonals as i have found that when we add the indexes, they are the same eg 00 or 01 10 or 12 21 11.....
But am not getting the logic fr dese diagonals

Comment: dude posting witty comments won't help.... i am new to this language so help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple logic I could think of is using two type of looping.. First in backward direction and second in forward direction. I'm not very sure whether this works for all cases, but you could follow something like this

```
public class MatrixDiagonal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m = 4, n = 5;
        int[][] matrix = {  { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 
                    { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
                    { 10, 11, 12, 12, 14 }, 
                    { 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 } };
        for(int j=n-1; j>=0; j--){
            for(int k=0; k<m; k++){
                if((j + k) < n){
                    System.out.print(matrix[k][j + k] + " ");
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for(int i=1; i<m; i++){
            for(int j=i, k=0; j<m && k<n; j++, k++){
                System.out.print(matrix[j][k] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check and reply